# Injecting different beans depending on provided environment property

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

So I have an application that can be started for several different countries for example:
mvn clean package -Dcountry=FRANCE
resp.
mvn clean package -Dcountry=GERMANY

For different countries I have different behavior especially when I'm validating stuff.

So I have this class that contains a country dependent validator:

```
@Component
public class SomeValidatingClass {

    private final Validator myCountrySpecificValidator;

    @Autowired
    public SomeValidatingClass(MyCountrySpecificValidator myCountrySpecificValidator) {
        this.myCountrySpecificValidator = myCountrySpecificValidator;
    }

    public void doValidate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        myCountrySpecificValidator.validate(target, errors);
    }
}
```

The first country dependent validator:

```
public class MyCountrySpecificValidator1 implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        if (target == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("field", "some error code");
        }
    }
}
```

The second country dependent validator:
Let's assume for

```
public class MyCountrySpecificValidator2 implements Validator {
   @Override
   public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       if (target != null) {
           errors.rejectValue("field", "some other error code");
       }
   }
}
```

My question is

- how do I manage to inject an instance of **MyCountrySpecificValidator1** into **SomeValidatingClass** when the application was startet with **"-Dcountry=FRANCE"**

and resp.

- how do I manage to inject an instance of **MyCountrySpecificValidator2** into **SomeValidatingClass** when the application was startet with **"-Dcountry=GERMANY"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `@Conditional` annotation to provide implementation depending on conditions. Like this

```
  @Bean(name="emailerService")
  @Conditional(WindowsCondition.class)
  public EmailService windowsEmailerService(){
      return new WindowsEmailService();
  }

  @Bean(name="emailerService")
  @Conditional(LinuxCondition.class)
  public EmailService linuxEmailerService(){
    return new LinuxEmailService();
  }
```

where e.g.

```
public class LinuxCondition implements Condition{

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux");  }
}
```

and you can use any property you need

or

use `@Profile` annotation defining active profile if you need multiple beans

read [here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/)

UPDATE:

Even simpler

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "country", havingValue = "GERMANY", matchIfMissing = true) and annotate a method which return the germany validator. And the same for France.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but one more question. How do inject the bean named "emailerService"? Autowiring does not work here right? DO I have to use a beans.xml or something alike?
Edit: Probably with @Resource

Comment: In fact you need just one `SomeValidatingClass ` bean. You define method annotated with `@Bean` and `@Conditional(FranceCondition.class)` returning the MyCountrySpecificValidator1  and marked as `@Conditional(GermanyCondition.class)` returningMyCountrySpecificValidator2 . and just use the bean. (only one of two is created according to the condition.